# redirect to login as part of session check

Tags: php

for the life of me can't get the header redirect or the java redirect to work in this lock.php

```html
<?php
include 'config.php' ;
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysqli_query($db,"select username from users where username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //confirm username from users table

$login_session=$row['username'];

if ($login_session ==""){
    // echo "the variable is empty"; //when i check this works here.
    //header ("Location: login.php"); //redirect to login -tried this, fail
    echo "<script> location.href='login.php'; </script>"; // tried this, fail
    exit(); //stop execution of any further script
}

?>
```

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: the header line (or script line) is not executing

Comment: Then what *is* happening?  Is there an error in the response or in the PHP logs?  What is the actual response from the server?  When you add more output for debugging, what happens?

Comment: If you're going to use the mysqli extension for database access (as opposed to the more modern PDO) you should at least use the object-oriented functions. The functions you're using now were designed as replacements for the ancient mysql functions and their use is generally not recommended in modern code.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, your code is currently open to SQL injection.  Whether you use the object-oriented style or the procedural style, you should use query parameters to treat input like values instead of directly injecting input as executable code.

Comment: @david, when debugging the SQL works fine. output is as expected. variable is set if session is set (user has previously logged in) when person has logged in, code drops through empty variable check, and on my index page welcome message with username works fine.  when variable check is empty = true. i have used simple echo to check variable is empty check and that works fine. but page redirect never works. page just stays on index.php (in browser address url) and page is blank. no error on browser page.

Comment: @whaley: *"i have used simple echo to check variable is empty check and that works fine"* - How have you confirmed this?  Is the content within the `if` block included in the output?

Comment: this in the php log...[10-Oct-2018 07:30:30 Australia/Sydney] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/swimmin2/public_html/cal_planning/lock.php on line 2
[10-Oct-2018 07:30:30 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/swimmin2/public_html/cal_planning/main.css:1) in /home/swimmin2/public_html/cal_planning/lock.php on line 10

Comment: @david, yeap, content within if block is in output

Comment: @whaley: If the `<script>` block is being output to the client as expected, and thus the server-side code is working as expected, then it doesn't seem that the problem is in the code shown.  When you use your browser's debugger, is that line of JavaScript code ever executed?  Is another error preventing it from being reached?

Comment: Is the above code the contents of `lock.php`? If not, what is? Also, what is the contents of `config.php`?

Comment: Hi @patrick Q  yeap. This is lock.php as an include on index.php. the config.php only includes db connection params and connection string. The db query works fine.... all be it should have injection protection....the if statement works fine.... when user not logged in drops through into if subroutine. But no redirect. Tested usin both header or java script. Both fail

Comment: @david. Away from keyboard sorry

Comment: The error messages that you provided a few comments above do not match the code in your question.

Comment: @whaley: The more you assure us that everything is "working fine" the less we can help you.  So far you've claimed that this code outputs to the browser exactly what you expect it to.  Which means this code *works*.  The problem is somewhere else.  Either that, or you're assuring us of incorrect assumptions on your part.

Comment: Too true @David. I have edited above with all surrounding code. as far as outputing to the browser, when I put various echos in spots through lock.php the logic in there outputs what i would expect. variable values, the array responce etc. but the output to heading is nothing.

Comment: To any out there that have had the same issues as me with this peice of code, move it to the <head> section of your page and the redirects and all work just fine. Apparently you are not allowed to ask debug questions here, but I thought it was appropriate as a PHP question, when this code is in <body> section of page, the redirect usining either script method or header method do not work (for me). I have seen the same comments on not being able to get this working in other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
if (empty($login_session)) { // You're checking for any empty/null value
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit; // Per php docs, header does not halt execution
}
```

You have an issue with your code.

- Checking if a value is blank is not the same as checking if it is 'null' or otherwise not assigned.

Comment: point 2 is wrong, you should always exit, after a header location redirect

Comment: I have tried !isset(  empty(  and the above, all cause the if statement to fire when no one is logged in.

Comment: @IdontDownVote, interesting catch -- I never realized header doesn't halt termination. I'll need to look at how I've previously implemented it as I've never run into issues, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @whaley I would recommend you do a var_dump of $_SESSION to see what's being stored, that will give you a good starting point.